# Can I create an alias in C# or VB.NET within method scope?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, scope, alias

Is there any equivalent to an aliasing statement such as:

```
// C#:
using C = System.Console;
```

or:

```
' VB.NET '
Imports C = System.Console
```

...but **within method scope** -- rather than applying to an entire file?

Comment: What would be a use case for such an alias? I can't think of any situation where this might be helpful.

Comment: 0xA3: I would imagine that he might wish to dynamically redirect a particular method to use a different class by the same name without changing any code. Not that I'm necessarily endorsing such a use, but it would/could make such a task easier, if not altogether intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

While this might be overkill, you could create a partial class and place only the functions you'd like the alias to apply to in their own file with the alias.

In the main class file:

```
/*Existing using statements*/   

namespace YourNamespace
{
    partial class Foo
    {

    }
}
```

In the other file:

```
/*Existing using statements*/   
using C = System.Console;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    partial class Foo
    {
        void Bar()
        {
            C.WriteLine("baz");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an object reference would be the logical way.  You are putting up a bit of an obstacle by using a static class.  Worked around like this:

```
   var c = Console.Out;
   c.WriteLine("hello");
   c.WriteLine("world");
```

Or the VB.NET With statement:

```
    With Console.Out
        .WriteLine("hello")
        .WriteLine("world")
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28VS.80%29.aspx) for more details.

Example:

```
namespace PC
{
    // Define an alias for the nested namespace.
    using Project = PC.MyCompany.Project;
    class A 
    {
        void M()
        {
            // Use the alias
            Project.MyClass mc = new Project.MyClass();
        }
    }
    namespace MyCompany
    {
        namespace Project
        {
            public class MyClass{}
        }
    }
}
```